# Error surrounding use of scan(&varlist) + Comparison of macro variables

Tags: sas, sas-macro

As a follow up to this question, for which my existing answer appears to be best: 
[Extracting sub-data from a SAS dataset & applying to a different dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650542/extracting-sub-data-from-a-sas-dataset-applying-to-a-different-dataset)

Given a dataset `dsn_in`, I currently have a set of macro variables `max_1` - `max_N` that contain numeric data. I also have a macro variable `varlist` containing a list of variables. The two sets of macros are related such that `max_1` is associated with `scan(&varlist, 1)`, etc. I am trying to do compare the data values within `dsn_in` for each variable in `varlist` to the associated comparison values `max_1` - `max_N`. I would like to output the updated data to `dsn_out`. Here is what I have so far:

```
data dsn_out;
  set dsn_in;

  /* scan list of variables and compare to decision criteria.
     if > decision criteria, cap variable */
  do i = 1 by 1 while(scan(&varlist, i) ~= '');
    if scan("&varlist.", i) > input(symget('max_' || left(put(i, 2.))), best12.) then   
    scan("&varlist.", i) = input(symget('max_' || left(put(i, 2.))), best12.);
  end;  
run;
```

However, I'm getting the following error, which I don't understand. `options mprint;` shown. SAS appears to be interpreting `scan` as both an array and a variable, when it's a SAS function.

```
ERROR: Undeclared array referenced: scan.
MPRINT(OUTLIERS_MAX):   if scan("var1 var2 var3 ... varN", i) > input(symget('max_' 
|| left(put(i, 2.))), best12.) then scan("var1 var2 var3 ... varN", i) = 
input(symget('max_' || left(put(i, 2.))), best12.);
ERROR: Variable scan has not been declared as an array.
MPRINT(OUTLIERS_MAX):   end;
MPRINT(OUTLIERS_MAX):   run;
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'll reiterate what I said in my earlier answer.  You are better off not using macro variables this way.  Keep data in datasets, and use the very, very powerful tools available to you in SAS for manipulating those datasets.

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure what "very, very powerful tools available" you're referring to. If you have time to update your prior response, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The specific issue you have here is that you place SCAN on the left side of an equal sign.  That is not allowed; SUBSTR is allowed to be used in this fashion, but not SCAN.